# Which hostname to choose from a group of zookeepers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am new to *distributed system*, and I am using docker to set up a group of **zookeeper**s.

For example, I have three **zookeeper**s started:

```
services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

  zoo2:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181
    environment: 
      ZOO_MY_ID: 2
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888

  zoo3:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 3
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
```

For starting a ***kafka***, I have to config its `server.properties`.
In the *zookeeper.connection=localhost:2181* example, what should I configure here?

```
zookeeper.connection=zoo1 / zoo2 / zoo3:2181?
```

or I should leave them three there? thanks

**[UPDATE]**

The ***kafka*** of course will be configured to be started within the same `docker-compose.yml` file.

But the `Dockerfile` of `kafka` was written locally. and I think that I should modify the `zookeeper.connect=...` in `server.properties` accordingly instead of using the `localhost`.

Comment: Is your kafka running on container of host ?

Comment: @BuiNgocLuan, yes, it was started by `docker-compose` within the same `docker-compose.yml`. so they should be in the same network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put all as comma separated list:

```
zookeeper.connect=zoo1:2181,zoo2:2181,zoo3:2181
```

So if one ZK goes down brokers can connect to a replica.

Comment: even thought I already found the answer, but thanks anyway, and you have the right answer.